# Testing Distributed File System

Tags: c++, filesystems, distributed-computing

I have been developing a robust distributed file system to be run on tcp/udp network.
I am writing the application in C++.

1. Currently I am looking for test framework that I can use for basic testing of the DFS.
   I am assuming I have to write some sort of plugin for the test framework.
2. As, I don't have bunch of computing power(have two machines). Also, would like to know ideas on whether to use some sort of simulator or buy some hardware for testing. Currently I am thinking about putting multiple VM's on my machines to create my test environment.
3. Test framework should be agnostic to network protocol being used. I am assuming most are, but not sure.

Any addition suggestions regarding test environment/framework would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using MIT's Star Cluster toolkit you can launch a cluster. Amazon provides free tier service, you can use that.